# Simulate holding down a key

Tags: c++, winapi, keypress, simulate

Im using:

```
keybd_event(0x41, 0, 0, 0);
```

0x41 is a 'a'. But that just prints one 'a' to the screen. I need it to **hold down** the key. And when i call

```
keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

it must release the key.

Is that possible?

Comment: are you trying to simulate the user holding down the 'A' key to get aaaa...?

Comment: You could use a timer or loop to continuously call keybd_event. Or, if you're aware of what hardware you're going to be on, you could pump keystrokes into the kb buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `keybd_event` call with [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx).  You can insert as many keystroke events as the event system will allow.  The function returns the number of events successfully inserted.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?  The keys that are intended to remain pressed should already do so with your first line.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) the documentation for keybd_event().  Maybe it will help answer your question.  (And maybe you needed the GetKeyboardState() method?)

If you're simply trying to repeatedly strike a key, it would be easier to loop around the first call than to try to get the system to auto-repeat.  You can find the proper delay to use in the system information API functions.

Comment: Hm, ok. Well hoped i could do it would a loop/timer. But i guess that will do the trick.